# Installing R 3.6.1 with conda hangs indefinitely

Tags: r, anaconda, installation, conda

I am running CentOS 7. If I run
`conda install r-base`
then conda installs R v3.5.3 successfully

However if I run
`conda install r-base=3.6.1`
then it fails over and over again on these two steps:

```
$ ./conda install r-base=3.6.1
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: - failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
```

And it looks like that version should be available:

```
$ conda search r-base
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
r-base                         3.1.2               0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.1.3               0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.1.3               1  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.1.3               2  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.2.0               0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.2.1               0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.2.2               0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.3.1               1  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.3.1               2  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.3.1               3  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.3.1               5  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.3.1               6  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.3.2               0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.3.2               1  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.3.2               2  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.3.2               3  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.3.2               4  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.3.2               5  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.4.1               0  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.4.1               0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.4.1               1  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.4.1               1  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.4.1               2  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.4.1               3  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.4.1               4  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.4.1      h4fe35fd_8  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.4.2      haf99962_0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.4.3      h1c2f66e_4  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.4.3      h1e0a451_2  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.4.3      h290ecf8_0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.4.3      h290ecf8_1  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.4.3      h9bb98a2_5  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.5.0      h1c2f66e_1  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.5.0      h1e0a451_1  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.5.1   h08e1455_1008  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.5.1      h1e0a451_2  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.5.1   h271c98b_1006  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.5.1      h391c2eb_4  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.5.1      h391c2eb_5  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.5.1   hbc19587_1011  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.5.1   hc461eb7_1012  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.5.1   he45234b_1004  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.5.1   he45234b_1005  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.5.1   hea2b9be_1007  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.5.1   hfb2a302_1009  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.5.1   hfb2a302_1010  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.5.3      h067a564_0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.5.3      h26b83e4_0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.6.0      hce969dd_0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.6.1      h3a67422_6  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.6.1      h6e652e1_3  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.6.1      h8900bf8_0  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.6.1      h8900bf8_1  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.6.1      h8900bf8_2  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.6.1      h9bb98a2_1  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.6.1      hba50c9b_4  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.6.1      hba50c9b_5  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.6.1      hce969dd_0  pkgs/r              
r-base                         3.6.2      h3a67422_0  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.6.2      h7ed4ef7_1  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.6.3      h7ed4ef7_0  conda-forge         
r-base                         3.6.3      h7ed4ef7_1  conda-forge
```

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have conflicting packages in your environment. Try creating a fresh one and install in there:

```
conda create -n newEnv -c conda-forge r-base=3.6.1
```